# Type for an interleaved array of classes and values

Tags: typescript

I'm building an API with a function that accepts an interleaved list of classes and initial values to assign to their instances.  Values must be assignable to an instance of their preceding class and can be omitted.  A call would look like this:

```
create(A, {x: 0, y: 0}, B, C, D, {w: 'foo'});
```

I tried defining a type like so:

```
interface Type<C> {
  new(): C;
}

type TypesWithInitializers<C> =
  [] |
  [Type<any>, ...TypesWithInitializers<any>] |
  [Type<C>, Partial<C>, ...TypesWithInitializers<any>];

function create(...args: TypesWithInitializers) {...}
```

This fails with the error "Type alias 'ComponentTypesWithInitializers' circularly references itself. ts(2456)".  I don't know how to work around this.

My understanding is that interfaces are allowed to be recursive, but I don't know how to replicate the rest operator in an interface, only how to declare either specific elements or all elements.  I also saw some examples with recursively defining a JSON structure that looked pretty similar to what I'm doing but I can't figure out what the critical difference is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't make a circular type alias, something like `type MyType = MyType` is illegal.

With the help of [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) I made something like the following?

```
register(Test, {x: 1, y: 3})
register(Test, OtherTest)
register(Test, {x: 1, y: 3}, OtherTest)
register(Test, {test: "Yo"}, OtherTest, {test: 4})
register(Test, {test: "Yo"}, OtherTest, {test: 4}, OtherTest, {test: 5})
register(Test, {test: "Yo"}, OtherTest, {test: 4}, OtherTest, {test: 5}, Test, Test)
```

The way it works is that we either have a bunch of `[Type, Object]` followed by a bunch of `[Types]`, the other way around or either of the two tuples.

My test type looks as following

```
@component
class Test {
    /** A test member of Test class */
    @prop(Type.int16) declare test: number
}

@component
class OtherTest {
    /** A test member of Test class */
    @prop(Type.int16) declare test: number
}
```

I then have constructed the tagged tuple union as follows

```
type Component =
| []
| [IType<any>]
| [IType<any>, Partial<any>]

type VariadicComponent = [...Component, ...Component]
```

The amount of `...Component` in `VariadicComponent` determines how many times we can flip flop between the tagged tuples. And the function signature then looks like this:

```
function register<G extends [...VariadicComponent]>(...args: [...G, ...G])
```

The `[...G, ...G]` is there so we can have different arg types. It doesn't work unless we have both `[...Component, ...Components]` **and** `[...G,...G]` in the code simultaneously.